# Aggregate by most recent N previous entries by category

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table and I'm trying to aggregate values of the most recent N values. In MSSQL you can reference an outer table in a subquery, but not in mysql so I'm trying to figure out another way to do this. Here's a super simplified version of what I'm working with:

```
gameid, teamid, gamedate, total
===============================
g1, A, 1/1/15, 1
g1, B, 1/1/15, 2
g2, A, 1/2/15, 3
g2, C, 1/2/15, 4
g3, B, 1/3/15, 5
g3, C, 1/3/15, 6
...
...
g5, A, 1/5/15, 7
...
g8, A, 1/8/15, 8
g8, B, 1/8/15, 9
```

As an example, let's say for each game/team combination I want to average the last 2 games that the team played. For the previous example, the output would look like this (with some comments from me)

```
gameid, teamid, AVG(total)
==========================
g1, A, NULL  <--- No games before this
g1, B, NULL
g2, A, 1.0   <--- Only one game before this
g2, C, NULL
g3, B, 2.0
g3, C, 4.0
...
g5, A, 2.0   <---- Two games before this
...
g8, A, 5.0   <---- Three games before this, only average last 2
```

I could get the average of all previous games by joining the table to itself like this, but I don't know how to limit it to the most recent N games:

```
SELECT g.gameid, g.teamid, g.gamedate, AVG(g1.total)
  FROM games g
  JOIN
       (SELECT teamid, gamedate, total
          FROM games) g1 ON g1.teamid = g.teamid
 WHERE g1.gamedate < g.gamedate
 GROUP BY g.gameid
 ORDER BY gameid DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

Got it Duder!

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af1f2b/18

```
SELECT
    teamid,
    avg(total),
    sub_table.lastgame,   
    sub_table.gamedate   
FROM
    (SELECT
            teamid,
            gameid as lastgame,
            total,
            gamedate,
            @rn:=CASE
                WHEN @var_teamid = teamid THEN @rn + 1
                ELSE 1
            END AS rn,
            @var_teamid:=teamid
    FROM
        (SELECT @var_teamid:=NULL, @rn:=NULL) vars, games

    ORDER BY teamid , gamedate DESC
    ) as sub_table WHERE
        rn <= 2 group by teamid order by teamid, gamedate desc
```

Comment: That limits the output of the query to 2 records. I need to limit the number of records going into the aggregation to 2 games. If I put the limit on the subquery, I wouldn't be able to control the date. It would LIMIT before the ordering and where clause filtering.

Comment: So you want the average of the points they scored in the last two games?   So like if in the last two games, team A scored 3 and 7 you would want it to say 5 ?

Comment: His dudeness, I got the two coming up with this crazy query I just posted in my answer.   Check it out.  I'm working on getting the avg now.  Let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Ahhhh user variables. Oh, man, my thinking about this case had become very uptight. This looks great, but I need the previous average for every game, not just the previous average for every team. Does that make sense? I'm gonna go ahead and mark it 8, and I think if I study up on user variables I should be able to abide.

Comment: I Appreciate that dude,   I want to get this for my own personal knowledge so I'm still fiddling with it.   Let me know if you find a solution and I'll do the same.   The dude abides :)

Answer (score 0):

@Notorious Pet0's got me moving in the right direction, and after a few sessions of wrestling with it arrived at my (fairly ugly) answer. [The results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/087d0/10) show exactly what I was looking for. Here's the SQL I came up with:

```
SELECT gid, tid, gdate, AVG(total)
  FROM (
        SELECT @r := IF(@c = Concat(gid, tid), @r + 1, 1) AS rownum, 
               @c := Concat(gid, tid), 
               prevgames.* 
          FROM (SELECT @c := NULL, @r := 0) AS _init 
          JOIN (
                SELECT gkey.gameid AS gid, 
                       gkey.teamid AS tid, 
                       gkey.gamedate AS gdate, 
                       gprev.* 
                  FROM games AS gkey 
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN games AS gprev 
                    ON (gkey.teamid = gprev.teamid AND gkey.gameid > gprev.gameid) 
                 ORDER BY gid, tid, gamedate DESC) AS prevgames
        ) AS g
WHERE rownum <= 2
GROUP BY gid, tid, gdate;
```